issue while creating war using gradle 8.6 the public/docs folder is not getting created
spring boot 2.7.6 having issue while creating war using
asciidoctor.jvm.convert 2.4.0 and spring docs 2.0.5
test {
 useJUnitPlatform()
   outputs.dir snippetsDir
 }
asciidoctor {
 configurations "asciidoctorExtensions"
 inputs.dir snippetsDir
 dependsOn test
   doLast {
     copy{
      from ("$buildDir/asciidoc/html5")
      into "$buildDir/resources/main/public/docs")
  include "**/*.html"
   }
  war {
 enabled = true
 dependsOn asciidoctor
}

War is getting created but the public docs folder is not there in the war.
war should contains /public/docs/*.html

is it to do something with gradle 8.6?

i figured out the issue in the ASCII version that I am using. The docs are saved to a different directory, i.e. /docs/asciidoc. so just by changing the
from ("$buildDir/asciidoc/html5") to  from ("$buildDir//docs/asciidoc").
It got resolved
